# How to get the RGB values of a color defined in a less file?

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js, less

I am using a JS framework named `D3` to draw graphs.

The framework requires the data in the following way (Note the hard coded colors):

```
graphData = [
    {
        data: [
        {
            date: "01/01/2015",
            value: 10
        }, 
        {
            date: "02/01/2015",
            value: 5
        }, 
        {
            date: "03/01/2015",
            value: 2
        }],
        label: 'Oranges',
        color: '#a3a3a3'
    }, 
    {
        data: [
        {
            date: "01/01/2015",
            value: 2
        }, 
        {
            date: "02/01/2015",
            value: 10
        }, 
        {
            date: "03/01/2015",
            value: 15
        }],
        label: 'Apples',
        color: '#424242',
    }]
```

In my `less` file I defined the following colors:

```
@Orange: #a3a3a;
@Apple: #424242;
```

How can I get the RGB colors defined in my less file while defining the  `graphData`?

Comment: It depends on many factors. Also, while it is possible to retrieve variable values from Less code (see for example [#2597](https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/2597) and tickets referenced there), usually it's more convenient to do things in opposite, i.e. by passing JS/JSON data to Less compiler (via `modifyVars` and so).

Answer (score 1):

You can use ajax request to fetch less file an find the colors:

Using jQuery it will look like this:

```js
$.get('file.less', function(file) {
  var orange = file.match(/@Orange:\s*([^;]+);/i)[1];
  var apple = file.match(/@Apple:\s*([^;]+);/i)[1];
});
```

without jQuery you will need to use XMLHttpRequest object.